# Magento 1: Multi website in Magento but Common checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

Would I like to know that is it really possible?

I have set up `multi-website` using `Magento 1.x`, but my requirement is whenever the customer adds the `product to cart`, then moves to check out than `checkout` will process on my main `website` domain.

Same like `Shopify`, in Shopify, whenever you check out they redirect the user to their fix domain that it something like chekckout.shopify.com

I don't know, but is it really possible in Magento?